# Get the size of the return type of a member function

Tags: c++, types, stl

I have classes/structs with member functions. I want to check that the return type has the correct size.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct QString {
    wchar_t ucs2() {return L"1"[0];}
};

int main() {
    QString arg;
    std::cout << "wchar_t   " << sizeof(wchar_t) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&QString::ucs2)(void)>   " << sizeof(std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&QString::ucs2)(void)>)  << std::endl;
}
```

Result is, for example,

```
wchar_t   4
std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&QString::ucs2)(void)>   16
```

so I get different sizes. I expected `std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&QString::ucs2)(void)` to be the return type of my ucs2 function, i.e. wchar_t, but it doesn't seem to be the  case. What is going on here?

Comment: `std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&QString::ucs2)(void)>` should be `std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&QString::ucs2)(QString)>`  as all member function take the class type as an implicit first parameter but it's not compiling for me.  What is really weird is `std::result_of_t<decltype(&QString::ucs2)(QString)>` does and it gives the correct result.

Comment: `decltype(&QString::ucs2)(void)` is the type of a function taking no arguments and returning a pointer-to-member function. That `16` is the size of the pointer to member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`invoke_result` is defined as:

```
template< class F, class... ArgTypes>
class invoke_result;
```

Hence, this is working

```
return sizeof(std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&QString::ucs2), QString>);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution:

```
int main() {
  std::cout << sizeof(QString().ucs2()) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The `QString()` default constructs a QString, which can then be used to call ucs2.  But since this all happens as an operand to sizeof, nothing is actually constructed or called.  The compiler does all the type analysis at compile time, even without  enabling optimizations.

Obviously, if you can't default construct the class, this may be less useful.